# Sometimes it's convenient to use ` read -t 3 ` instead of ` sleep 3 `. How do I make it work with `nohup`?

Tags: bash, nohup, read, sleep

Sometimes it's convenient to use `read -t 3` instead of `sleep 3`. How do I make it work with `nohup`?

```
nohup bash -c ' date; read -t 3; date ' | tail -n 2 nohup.out
```

As you can see, `read -t 3` does not wait for three seconds.

Comment: How is that convenient or a substitute for sleep? `read -t 3` is to read from standard input with a 3 second timeout. With `nohup`, it's `/dev/null` from which reads return straight away. Also stdout and stderr are redirected by nohup to the nohup.out so it makes little sense to pipe to `tail`, especially considering that you're telling `tail` not to read its stdin (by giving it a file to read as argument instead). What is it exactly that you want to do?

Comment: If you want a shell with builtin sleeping support, look at `zsh` (`zselect`) or `mksh`/`ksh93` (`sleep` builtin) instead of `bash`.

Comment: Well, `tail` was just for the sake of demonstration ((or) to help the reader with a quick test). I only need `read` to play its input role when not under nohup, otherwise I'm fine with its sleep role. So essentially my question is how do I make `read` not break on those rarer occasions when I need to use nohup. Perhaps some kind of virtual `stdin` that could make it happy and do the waiting?

Comment: where do you want it to read from when under nohup? nohup is meant to detach a command from the terminal it's started from, so you wouldn't want to read from the terminal device in that. If you're using `read` as a sleep substitute  that can be shortened by the user pressing enter, then it seems to me that returning straight away when under nohup (so when not interactive) is the right thing to do.

Comment: I don't want any read *in those rare cases*. I just want it to not break but to *sleep*.

Comment: Then `read` is not the right tool. For sleeping, just use `sleep`. That's what it's for. Doing a `read` on the terminal would also mean that your script would be suspended when it's run in background.

Comment: If you want to _read with timeout_ if stdin is a terminal device and _sleep_ otherwise, then it would be `if [ -t 0 ]; then read -t 3; else sleep 3; fi`

Comment: Having to add this condition is not a problem for me. So this answers my question. Do you think I should delete this question?

Comment: I'll add an answer. There's always a chance that the Q&A would be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read -t 3` (a `ksh93` extension now also supported by `zsh`, `bash` and `mksh`) is meant to read one line (*logical* line in that lines may be continued with a trailing backslash as you don't use the `-r` option) from stdin into `$REPLY` with a 3 second timeout.

If stdin is a terminal, that will sleep for 3 seconds unless the user presses enter (and the script will be suspended with a SIGTTIN signal if it's started in background).

If it's a regular file, it will read that line from it and return straight away. If it's `/dev/zero` it will do a very busy read of gigabytes of zeros from there, etc.

`nohup` is the command you use to detach a command from a terminal. It redirects stdin to `/dev/null` and stdout and stderr to `nohup.out`. So typically you would *not* want to read from the terminal in that case.

`read` on `/dev/null` returns straight away with no data returned, that's what `/dev/null` is for.

If the purpose of using `read -t` is to have a kind of sleep that can be interrupted by the user (by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>) like when you want to give them the time to read a message which they can skip, then having `read -t` return straight away  when non-interactive (like when running under `nohup`) would seem the right thing to do as there's no point delaying the script then.

But if you want to read from the terminal with timeout if stdin is a terminal, and sleep otherwise, then you would do:

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
  read -t 3
else
  sleep 3
fi
```

`[ -t n ]` tests whether the file descriptor *n* (0 being stdin) refers to a terminal device.

You could do `read -t 3 < /dev/tty` but that would defeat the purpose of `nohup` by adding back the interaction with the terminal that `nohup` is meant to guard against.

Comment: As I implied above, I wouldn't mind deleting my question. I knew (why) the community wouldn't like it before the downvoting began. I agree that it broke some of their rules or expectations. I'm not suggesting that I agree to those rules; I don't; but on stackexchange I will not offer something that is not desired. I don't regret that I didn't delete my question, because I like your answer and I need it to stay here. I am a beginner so I guess the best way to frame my question is: is it improper for me to ask you to turn it into a Community Wiki post?